# How to check is a user input is in a Excel column using openpyxl module

Tags: python, excel, windows, openpyxl

I'm writing a Python script to manipulate Excel files, I'm using the openpyxl module, does anybody know how can I check if a user input is in a column, I've done this:

```
def esta():
    for itemChecker in inventory["A"]:
        if itemChecker == newItem:
            item_on = True
        if itemChecker != newItem:
            item_on = False


newItem = input("New Item: ")
itemChecker = " "
item_on = False
esta()
if item_on == False:
    print("Item isn't on the column")
if item_on == True:
    print("Item is on the column")
```

The code inside the "esta()" function does the following: If the user input (newItem) is in the "A" column of  the variable assigned to an Excel file called "inventory",  the variable "item_on" is set equal to True, if the user input isn't in the "A" column, "item_on" is set equal to False. The if statement does this: If item_on is equal to False (that means that the user input isn't on the column) it prints "Item isn't on the column", but if item_on is equal to True (the user input is on the column) it prints "Item is on the column".
What am I doing wrong? I'm not getting any errors but it always prints "Item isn't on the column" even when I know item is on the column. Please I need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer:
Add a `break`.

We should have the code terminate when it finds the value in the column. Otherwise, it will go on searching in other cells of the column where the value is not present, thus, resulting in item_on being set to False.

Also, in your code you are setting `item_on` to False, outside the function.
`item_on` inside `esta` being set to true will have no effect to the `item_on` outside it.

something like this should do the trick: if all the code is in the same scope.

```
def esta():
    for itemChecker in inventory["A"]:
        if itemChecker == newItem:
            item_on = True
            break
```

Though I think you should use `esta` as a funciton.

```
def esta():
    for itemChecker in inventory["A"]:
        if itemChecker == newItem:
            return True
    return False


newItem = input("New Item: ")
itemChecker = " "

# assign the value of esta to a variable
item_on = esta()

# remove redundant check for True / False (refer to https://pep8.org)
if item_on:
    print("Item is on the column")
else:
    print("Item isn't on the column")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: may I suggest accepting it as the answer, by clicking on the tick mark below upvote/downvote option, if the answer did really help you.